# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I am trying to return collection and assign it to a listbox but I am getting following error

> *"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List to
>   'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection"*

I am new to WPF & C# I got no clue how to handle this.

All I want to do is load all videos in My Videos folder into listbox containing media element control.

What would be the correct way to return?

Code:

```
public class Video 
{
    public Uri SourceUri { get; set; }

    public static ObservableCollection<Video> LoadVideoInfo()
    {
        List<Video> videoresult = new List<Video>();

            foreach (string filename in
            System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(
            Environment.GetFolderPath(
            Environment.SpecialFolder.MyVideos)))

            videoresult.Add(new Video { SourceUri = new UriBuilder(filename).Uri });

        return videoresult;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="VideoList" ItemsSource="{Binding }" Width="auto" Height=" auto" Margin="5,0,5,2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <MediaElement Source="{Binding SourceUri}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
ObservableCollection<Video> videoresult = new ObservableCollection<Video>();
```

Answer (score 4):

Your method says it returns a `ObservableCollection<Video>` but you return a `List<Video>`.
Create a `ObservableCollection<Video>` and return it.

```
return new ObservableCollection<Video>(videoresult);
```

### Multieple DataContexts:

### *ContextModel*

```
public class ContextModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Video> Videos { get; set; }
    public object OtherContext { get; set; }
}
```

### *Main Window*

```
this.DataContext = new ContextModel()
{
    Videos = Video.LoadVideoInfo(),
    OtherContext = LoadOtherContext()
};
```

### *Main Window Xaml*

```
<ListBox x:Name="VideoList" ItemsSource="{ Binding Videos }" />
<ListBox x:Name="OtherListBox" ItemsSource="{ Binding OtherContext }" />
```

Comment: Thank you this solved the error, but i am unable to get videos loaded into the list box, I am posting xaml part here, please help

Comment: Your ItemSource is defined as '{ Binding }' What is the datacontext?

Comment: this is datacontext DataContext = Video.LoadVideoInfo();

Comment: I created a small test application, but I don't have an error. (except perhaps that if you have more than 1 video (they all start playing at the same time :p)

Comment: @badrulmuneer My working test app can be found in [my skydrive](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=42FA0BD534D1D672!168&authkey=!APvbi024iiIWxP4)

Comment: Thank you for your time, I am able to load all the videos. The problem was I was using one more datacontext for loading the images into other listbox, one commenting that videos got loaded, can you please tell me how can I use both datacontexts? @SynerCoder

Comment: Cheers Mate that worked, you explained it wonderfully. Thank you @SynerCoder

Answer (score 0):

in return statement, use the following code.

```
return (new ObservableCollection(videoresult));
```

Answer (score 0):

you should change in return type , return type should be ObservableCollection instead of List.